# Implementing Runge-Kutta for Systems of DE

Tags: matlab, differential-equations, numerical-analysis

I'm trying to implement the [Runge-Kutta Method for Systems of DEs](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/189/rkforde.png/) in MATLAB. I'm not getting the [correct answers](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/802/591hw.png/), I'm not sure if there is something wrong in the code or the commands I use to run it.

Here's my code:

```
function RKSystems(a, b, m, N, alpha, f)
    h = (b - a)/N;
    t = a;
    w = zeros(1, m);

    for j = 1:m
        w(j) = alpha(j);
    end

    fprintf('t = %.2f;', t);
    for i = 1:m
        fprintf(' w(%d) = %.10f;', i, w(i));
    end
    fprintf('\n');

    k = zeros(4, m);
    for i = 1:N
        for j = 1:m
           k(1, j) = h*f{j}(t, w);
        end

        for j = 1:m
            k(2, j) = h*f{j}(t + h/2, w + (1/2)*k(1));
        end

        for j = 1:m
            k(3, j) = h*f{j}(t + h/2, w + (1/2)*k(2));
        end

        for j = 1:m
            k(4, j) = h*f{j}(t + h, w + k(3));
        end

        for j = 1:m
            w(j) = w(j) + (k(1, j) + 2*k(2, j) + 2*k(3, j) + k(4, j))/6;
        end

        t = a + i*h;

        fprintf('t = %.2f;', t);
        for k = 1:m
            fprintf(' w(%d) = %.10f;', k, w(k));
        end
        fprintf('\n');

    end 
end
```

I'm trying to test it out on [this problem](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/534/591hwprob.png/).
Here are my commands and output:

> >> U1 = @(t, u) 3*u(1) + 2*u(2) - (2*t^2 + 1)*exp(2*t);
>
> >> U2 = @(t, u) 4*u(1) + u(2) + (t^2 + 2*t - 4)*exp(2*t);
>
> >> a = 0; b = 1; alpha = [1 1]; m = 2; h = 0.2; N = (b - a)/h;
>
> >> RKSystems(a, b, m, N, alpha, {U1 U2});
>
> t = 0.00; w(1) = 1.0000000000; w(2) = 1.0000000000;
>
> t = 0.20; w(1) = 2.2930309680; w(2) = 1.6186020410;
>
> t = 0.40; w(1) = 5.0379629523; w(2) = 3.7300162165;
>
> t = 0.60; w(1) = 11.4076339762; w(2) = 9.7009491301;
>
> t = 0.80; w(1) = 27.0898576892; w(2) = 25.6603894354;
>
> t = 1.00; w(1) = 67.1832886708; w(2) = 67.6103125539;

Comment: You might be interested in MATLAB `ode45` function that solves ODE’s with RK: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problems were in the following lines of code:

`k(2, j) = h*f{j}(t + h/2, w + (1/2)*k(1));`

`k(3, j) = h*f{j}(t + h/2, w + (1/2)*k(2));`

`k(4, j) = h*f{j}(t + h, w + k(3));`

I was expecting `k(1)` to add the entire first row of `k` (a 4 by m matrix) to the matrix `w` (a 1 by m matrix), but it was only adding the first element of the first row. To fix it, I modified the lines as follows:

`k(2, j) = h*f{j}(t + h/2, w + (1/2)*k(1, :));`

`k(3, j) = h*f{j}(t + h/2, w + (1/2)*k(2, :));`

`k(4, j) = h*f{j}(t + h, w + k(3, :));`

Answer (score 2):

So... here is how I would do it, it is very difficult for me to read what is going on in your code snippet, but I hope this helps you out. Additionally, matlab has built in rk solvers I would suggest becoming familiar with those.

```
%rk4 solver
dt = .2;
t = 0:dt:1;
u = zeros(2,numel(t));
u(:,1) = 1;

for jj = 2:numel(t)
    u_ = u(:,jj-1);
    t_ = t(jj-1);
    fa = rhs(u_,t_);
    fb = rhs(u_+dt/2.*fa,t_+dt/2);
    fc = rhs(u_+dt/2.*fb,t_+dt/2);
    fd = rhs(u_+dt.*fc,t_+dt);
    u(:,jj) = u(:,jj-1) + dt/6*(fa+2*fb+2*fc+fd);
end
disp([t;u]')
```

and rhs.m is the following:

```
function dudt = rhs(u,t)
dudt = [(3*u(1) + 2*u(2) - (2*t^2 + 1)*exp(2*t));
        (4*u(1) + u(2) + (t^2 + 2*t - 4)*exp(2*t))];
```

This returns the following:

```
>> rkorder4
     0    1.0000    1.0000
0.2000    2.1204    1.5070
0.4000    4.4412    3.2422
0.6000    9.7391    8.1634
0.8000   22.6766   21.3435
1.0000   55.6612   56.0305
```

Alternatively, you could invoke ode45 with something like:

```
dt = .2;
t = 0:dt:1;
rhs=@(t,u)[(3*u(1) + 2*u(2) - (2*t^2 + 1)*exp(2*t));
        (4*u(1) + u(2) + (t^2 + 2*t - 4)*exp(2*t))];

[ts,us]=ode45(@(t,u) rhs(t,u),t,[1 1],[]);
disp([ts us]);
```

Which gives you:

```
                   0   1.000000000000000   1.000000000000000
   0.200000000000000   2.125018862140859   1.511597928697035
   0.400000000000000   4.465156492097592   3.266022178547346
   0.600000000000000   9.832481410895053   8.256418221678395
   0.800000000000000  23.003033457636558  21.669270713784108
   1.000000000000000  56.738351357036301  57.106230777717208
```

Which is pretty close to what you get from my code. The agreement between the two can be increased by decreasing the time step, `dt`. They will always be in greatest agreement at the low values of t with the difference between the two increasing as t increases. Both implementations are also in pretty close agreement with the analytic solutions.

Comment: Cool. Did you use the algorithm from the image I posted to come up with your version of the RK4, or did you use other sources?

Comment: I used some of my old code which was informed by the link at the end of this comment. As far as I can tell, the approach I took and the one from your image are equivalent. A great free resource for this kind of stuff is this textbook: http://courses.washington.edu/amath581/581.pdf

Comment: @johnish very nice code! I have being studying both the question and the answer of this post because I am facing a big problem trying to solve a system (2x2) of first order odes. I have tried to use your codes but my problem is that I don't have an explicit function, I have a discrete function. This means that I have something like: `U1 @(t,u) 3*P1*u(1).*P2*u(2)` and `U2 @(t,u) 34.5*P1*u(1).*P2*u(2)` where `P1,P2` are arrays(!) Any suggestion?

Comment: @badjr I have being studying both the question and the answer of this post because I am facing a big problem trying to solve a system (2x2) of first order odes. I have tried to use your codes but my problem is that I don't have an explicit function, I have a discrete function. This means that I have something like: `U1 @(t,u) 3*P1*u(1).*P2*u(2)` and `U2 @(t,u) 34.5*P1*u(1).*P2*u(2)` where `P1,P2` are arrays(!) Any suggestion?

Comment: @SergioHaram It has been a while since I've worked on this, so I don't remember the details. I see you have asked a separate question on your specific problem, which is probably the best thing to do. Hopefully someone else can answer your question.